# Creating an Excel spreadsheet with information from two Repositories

Tags: java, jxls

I want to create a report that pulls in all licenses and insurances, from their separate repositories, into an excel sheet. Is there a way to do it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/report/expirationReport")
public void getExpirationReport(Model model,HttpServletResponse response){
    List<License> licenses;
    List<Insurance> insurances;
    licenses = licenseRepository.findAll();
    insurances = insuranceRepository.findAll();

    List<String> headers=Arrays.asList("Legal Name","Principle Name","Type","State","Expiration");
    response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExpirationReport.xls");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    try {
        new SimpleExporter().gridExport(headers, licenses, insurances,"client.legalName, client.principleName,type,state,expiration", response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Both repositories already exist, but I can't just add the Insurances in (like I did above) because the SimpleExporter seems to only be accepting two objects and then the object props. Any idea how to get it to accept all three objects? Or any idea how to best concatenate/save the two repo findAll function results into one data object?

Edit: 
I was able to get this to work by going through the Client table, as license and insurances both had foreign keys to client. Here's the code:

```html
@RequestMapping(value="/report/expirationReport")
public void expirationReport(HttpServletResponse response){
    List<Client> clients=clientRepository.findAll();

        try {
            response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=expirationReport.xlsx");
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            InputStream is= new ClassPathResource("static/reports/expirationReport.xlsx").getInputStream();
            Context context= new Context();
            context.putVar("clients", clients);

            JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is,response.getOutputStream(),context);
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`licenses` and `insurances` are two separate lists that have programmatically nothing in common. The could be different in size, so that JXLS won't know at which row it should be used.

Therefore JXLS supports only a single `Iterable` in `gridExport()`. Your best bet is to join your lists together. It is up to you to decide whether to join them in the repository or a separate service (or hacked inside the controller), but it must definitely be a single collection.

Comment: Thanks @Thunderhook. I was able to mostly get this to work, using JXLS and a table called clients, because both insurance and licenses have a foreign key with clients. Now I am only having an issue that it only prints the client name once but there may be multiple licenses for one client, so if anyone sorts the  excel file, they get scrambled around, some without names.

Comment: I think the best you could do is to create a ``ExpirationDTO`` containing all fields that an excel row represents. Then you provide a method which merges all your connected data (clients, insurances, ...) into a ``List<ExpirationDTO>`` which then holds the data which excel would display. Then you're in control how often the client is shown (when it is set inside the DTO).

Comment: That makes since. Thanks @thunderhook !